# MSACESS - JOIN expression not supported error

Tags: sql, ms-access

When I run this on Microsoft Access:

```
SELECT
  'BANNER',
  USRAUDT_KEY_VALUE_1,
  UCRACCT_PREM_CODE,
  CONCAT(CONCAT(USRAUDT_KEY_VALUE_1,'_'),UCRACCT_PREM_CODE) AS "ACCOUNT",
  USRAUDT_USER_ID,
  ' ',
  ' ',
  USRAUDT_ACTIVITY_DATE,
  ' ',
  'bill cycle',
  ' ',
  UCRACCT_STATUS_IND,
  USRAUDT_NEW_VALUE,
  ' ',
  UCRACCT_BILL_PRES_TYPE
FROM
  USRAUDT
  INNER JOIN UCRACCT ON (USRAUDT_KEY_VALUE_1) = UCRACCT_CUST_CODE
WHERE 1=1
  AND USRAUDT_NEW_VALUE In ('E','R')
  and USRAUDT_USER_ID <> 'UEADMIN'
  and USRAUDT_COLUMN_NAME='UCBCUST_PAPERLESS_IND'
  and (USRAUDT_ACTIVITY_DATE >= '27-JAN-2020')  
  and (USRAUDT_ACTIVITY_DATE <= '03-FEB-2020')  
  and ((USRAUDT_TABLE_NAME)='UCBCUST') 
  AND UCRACCT_STATUS_IND='A'
  and UCRACCT_BILL_PRES_TYPE in ('E','L','U','V')
```

I get the error "Join expression NOT supported", I've tried using AND but still no avail. Help please.. :(

Comment: I am not completely familiar with MS Access, but why are naming your column with a parenthesis? Columns in SQL should only use alphabetical characters and numbers, Also try to use aliases (AS A, AS B after each table name). Hopefully that helps. Let me know if not

Comment: Is `USRAUDT_KEY_VALUE_1` the name of a column in table `USRAUDT`? Or is the name of the column `KEY_VALUE_1`?

Comment: You code is _T-SQL_ which is not compatible with _Access SQL_.

Answer (score 0):

No two SQL dialects are exactly the same including MS Access SQL and others from various DBMS's. Specifically, your attempted query includes several issues:

- **Join**: `ON` clauses in MS Access requires table or table alias qualifiers with period notations. Generally in SQL, the best practice is to qualify *every* column reference in `SELECT`, `ON`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and other clauses whenever you join more than one table. This facilitates code maintainability and readability.

  ```
  FROM USRAUDT d
  INNER JOIN UCRACCT c 
     ON d.USRAUDT_KEY_VALUE_1 = d.UCRACCT_CUST_CODE
  ```
- **Functions**: There is no built-in `CONCAT` function. Use `&` instead or build your own via VBA function (accessible through queries only in MS Access GUI and not backend via ODBC/OLEDB): `d.USRAUDT_KEY_VALUE_1 & '_' & c.UCRACCT_PREM_CODE`
- **Quotes**: Double even single quotes used in column aliases will render such symbols (`"`, `'`) directly in query column headers. Similarly, if you use quotes for table aliases, you will then need to reference table with such symbols. For example, `SELECT "d".* FROM USRAUDT "d"` or `SELECT 'd'.* FROM USRAUDT 'd'` works but fails if you use no quotes: `SELECT d.* ...`. To escape special characters or spaces in MS Access, use square brackets or backticks. Column and table names are case insensitive in Access regardless of symbols.
- **Aliases**: Any columns without column names or aliases will render as `Expr####` where number follows 1000 + column integer (zero-index). To avoid this result, provide actual column aliases even for constants like `'_'` unless `SELECT` is used in insert-select query which does not matter. Again, generally in SQL, the best practice is to always provide unique column aliases as some other engines will raise exceptions.
- **Dates**: Dates in MS Access cannot be compared to its string representation but need to be casted to dates with `CDate` or enclosed with `#` and must adhere to representative forms of dates such as `'MM/DD/YYYY'` or `'DD/MM/YYYY'`. Usually, the best format though is [ISO system date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): `'YYYY-MM-DD'`:

  ```
  and (d.USRAUDT_ACTIVITY_DATE >= #2020-01-27#)  
  and (d.USRAUDT_ACTIVITY_DATE <= CDate('02/03/2020')
  ```